# Grep unix for a data to find out result

Tags: linux, grep

i have a file, contains huge data.
for example there is written "COST-> 1.00" line. and i would like to grep for example between 1.00 and 100. it includes both integer and string characters. how should i make grep for this data?

thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest using a tool like `awk` or `perl` that would allow you to do direct numeric comparisons instead of `grep` (which relies on comparing values lexically)

Answer (score 0):

You could match the first part of the pattern

`grep "COST -> 1" hugedatafile.txt`

but this would also match entries of
COST -> 143

So we need to fancy it up a bit

`grep -e "[1-9]\.|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]|100" hugedatafile.txt`

The "|" is an 'or' switch for extended grep. There are 3 conditions being tested here. Any number between 1.0 and 9.(whatever decimal) or any number between 10.0 and 99.(whatever decimal) or 100 will be matched. Extended grep may not be available on all distributions so your mileage may vary.